# Assign default values to fields if they return empty

Tags: apex

If I have a custom setting with some fields and I want to query those fields, in my controller I'm doing the following:

```
public My_Custom_Setting__c getMyCustomSetting() {
    return = [select URL__c, Title__c from My_Custom_Setting__c];
}
```

If these fields are empty, I want to assign default values to them.

Something like the following:

```
public My_Custom_Setting__c getMyCustomSetting() {
    String title;
    String url;

    My_Custom_Setting__c cs = [select URL__c, Title__c from My_Custom_Setting__c];

    title = cs.Title__C || 'Title default';
    url = cs.URL__c || 'URL default';

    cs.Title__C = title;
    cs.URL__c = url;

    return cs;
}
```

I'm getting the following error when attempting to save:

```
Save error: OR operator can only be applied to Boolean expressions
```

So I can't use `||` in this way.

How do I assign my default values to my returned object?

Am I approaching this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways to do that :

```
if (!String.isBlank(cs.Title__c)){
    title = cs.Title__c ;
} else {
    title = 'Title default';
}
```

Or

```
title = (!String.isBlank(cs.Title__c)) ? cs.Title__c : 'Title default';
```

This is one seems silimar to what you tried to do

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about `isBlank`. Cheers!